# Can I increase the "constant on" speed of my air handler?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I have an American Standard TWE049E13CB air handler with a variable speed blower. The manual has a chart to adjust the dip switches for fan speeds for cooling, heating, fan off delay, and auxilary heat. I don't see anything to adjust the speed when the thermostat is set to fan always on.

In my two story home, even with additional attic insulation, it gets stuffy in the middle of the night. I estimate the fan runs at 30%-50% full speed when it is not cooling. Is there a way too increase the fan speed when the system is only circulating air and not cooling.

Comment: Are you willing to hack your furnace controls? This will void any warranties. If so, we could talk of rewiring the controls. Otherwise, you have to accept the way the manufacturer designed it.

Comment: That's what I figured.

Comment: I don't have a warranty as I am not the original owner.  I am considering doing this as my other option would be zoning of some sort.  Maybe moving the thermostat upstairs would work.

Comment: Would adding an air return in my basement help pull the cold air that drops into the basement back into the rest of the house?

Comment: Yes but if you pull cool air out of the basement you will pull warm humid wire into it. This leads to higher moisture in the basement and a damp, musty basement. I tried this years ago by opening the return air on the furnace and using a box fan to blow air upstairs. It did make the upstairs slightly cooler but eventually made the basement quite humid and damp.

Comment: It sounds like you should investigate a whole house fan to use for night-time cooling.

Comment: I have a radon system that has made the basement quite dry. Maybe that will counteract?

Comment: Wow.  My return duct already had a 6" inch hole cut out for testing or installing of the UV bulb (which I don't use).  I removed the flat plate that sealed this up and the results are way better than I had hoped.  the basement is warmer and the upstairs is cooler.